# how come my backup script fails to build the tar.gz file and send it over scp?

Tags: bash, scripting, backup, scp, compression

I'm trying to create a script to automate MySQL backups and transfer the generated file to another server.

I managed to create the dump file, but haven't made much progress from that point. The script so far is pasted bellow.

```
#!/bin/bash

# database credentials
DATABASEHOST="<url>"
DATABASEUSER="<user>"
DATABASEPASSWORD="<password>"
DATABASESCHEMA="<schema>"
DATABASEENV="<env>"

# Local directory of mysqldump file
LOCALDIR=/home/<user>/db-bkp

# Temporary directory for compressed file
TEMPDIR=/home/<user>/tmp

# Remote Directory for backups.
REMOTEDIR=/home/<user>/db-bkp

# Backup host to login to
BACKUPHOST=<backup-host>
#--- end config


echo $(date +%H:%M)
echo "Creating the MySQL dump" 
mysqldump --host="$DATABASEHOST" --user="$DATABASEUSER" --password="$DATABASEPASSWORD" --single-transaction "$DATABASESCHEMA" > "$LOCALDIR"/"$(date +%Y%m%d)_bkp_$DATABASESCHEMA.sql"

#echo "Generating md5sum"
md5sum "$LOCALDIR"/* > "$LOCALDIR"/checklist.chk

#echo "Compressing the dump and checklist"
tar -cvzf "$TEMPDIR"/"$(date +%Y%m%d"_"$DATABASEENV"_"$DATABASESCHEMA".tar.gz "$LOCALDIR"/*

#echo "Sending the compressed file to d2"
scp "$TEMPDIR"/"$DATABASESCHEMA".tar.gz "$BACKUPHOST":"$REMOTEDIR"

#echo "Removing generated files"
#rm "$LOCALDIR"/checklist.chk > /dev/null 2>&1

#rm "$LOCALDIR"/"$(date +%Y%m%d)_bkp_$DATABASESCHEMA.sql" > /dev/null 2>&1

#rm "$TEMPDIR"/"$DATABASESCHEMA".tar.gz > /dev/null 2>&1

echo $(date +%H:%M)
```

Since I'm still testing it, I do a lot of manual runs but on the few last executions it managed to create the dump file and the md5sum hash but stopped there.

```
<user>@<host>:~/db-bkp$ ./dev_backup.sh 
10:45
Creating the MySQL dump
./dev_backup.sh: line 48: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./dev_backup.sh: line 51: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Funny thing is that lines 48 and 51 ar commented out. What's going on here?

Comment: Next time you post error messages with line numbers in them, *don’t post an abridged copy of the script!*   Or, if you do, generate line numbers ***and then*** delete the line(s) you want to delete, so we can tell which line was line 48 and which line (if any) was line 51 when you ran the script and got the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the above code running "bash -n" gives the following output:

```
line 42: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
line 45: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

So change the tarball creation command to the following:

```
tar -cvzf "$TEMPDIR"/$(date +%Y%m%d)"_"$DATABASEENV"_"$DATABASESCHEMA".tar.gz" "$LOCALDIR"/*
```

I suppose this should work.

Comment: testing it now...

Comment: You should always quote shell variables (e.g., `"$DATABASEENV"` and `"$DATABASESCHEMA"`) and command substitutions (like `"$(date …)"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing. By contrast, you don’t need to quote constant strings that don’t contain any special characters (e.g., `"_"` and `".tar.gz"`), although it generally doesn’t hurt.  It’s true that concatenating shell variables and constant strings can be problematic; you can handle that by doing `"$TEMPDIR/$(date +%Y%m%d)_${DATABASEENV}_$DATABASESCHEMA.tar.gz"` — see [this](/q/32210/23408#286525).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by minimizing the number of quotes being used:

```
tar -cvzf \
    "$TEMPDIR/$(date '+%Y%m%d')_$DATABASEENV\_$DATABASESCHEMA.tar.gz" \
    "$LOCALDIR"/* \
;
```

Note that you were missing the closing the parens for the `$(date..` command which was not easily spotted due to the density of quotes.

Comment: (1) I already gave a minimal-quotes version of the command argument a few hours ago.  (2) If `DATABASEENV` is `foo` and `DATABASESCHEMA` is `bar`, then `"$DATABASEENV\_$DATABASESCHEMA.tar.gz"` is ``foo\_bar.tar.gz``.  The OP’s code (once the trivial error is fixed) gives `foo_bar.tar.gz`, so that is probably what he wants.

Comment: Yes you are right on both counts.

Answer (score -1):

this is more beautiful

```
tar czvf ${TEMPDIR}/$(date +%Y%m%d)_${DATABASEENV}_${DATABASESCHEMA}.tar.gz ${LOCALDIR}/*
```

Comment: You should always quote all shell variable references (e.g., `"$TEMPDIR"`, `"$DATABASEENV"`, `"$DATABASESCHEMA"`, and `"$LOCALDIR"`) and command substitutions (like `"$(date …)"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.   By contrast, while braces can be important, they’re not as important as quotes — see [this](/q/32210/23408#286525) — so, while this may be “more beautiful” than the accepted answer, it is less safe.

Comment: Thanks @Scott ! I forgot about white space and special char in variable.